# Were there civilian female test pilots in the 60's?

Tags: aviation-history, flight-testing

In [1962](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.a0000094904&view=1up&seq=1&skin=2021), women couldn't become astronauts because NASA had a requirement that astronauts be experimental jet test pilots. In the 60's, were there any civilian test pilots that tested planes that weren't jet planes? Were there any female test pilots that tested planes that weren't jet planes?

Answer (score 1):

I looked for the US (as you also mentioned NASA) without success, but as you're asking for names worldwide I'm replying with famous French test pilots that come to my mind.

**Were there any female test pilots that tested planes that weren't jet planes?**

In France the first women to test planes, [Adrienne Bolland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrienne_Bolland), did it in 1920, indeed this was on aircraft with piston engines.

**Were there civilian female test pilots in the 60's?**

[Jacqueline Auriol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacqueline_Auriol) worked as a test pilot for [Brétigny flight test center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_du_personnel_navigant_d%27essais_et_de_r%C3%A9ception) from end of 50s and till 71. In 1962 she set her fifth world speed record.